# Divide an article into passages when html input is given

Tags: python, html

Input : Html content | Output: List of passages with subheadings(if present)
The problem is my article will contain subheadings in the format of heading tags, Bold tags, Stronger tags which may be present in div tags. We cannot assure that only these tags will represent headings. I have to split the articles into passages with headings(if present) no matter how the input html is and return list of passages.

I thought of converting html to markdown and parse it. Here's how I tried with regex. But I need to know whether there are any other approaches or fine tune this bit of code itself.
Need to be careful while splitting because we should not split the bold tags that is present inside the passages.

```
import re

def markdown_to_passages(markdown_text):
    pattern = r'^#{1,6}\s*(.*?)$|(?:\*{2,3}|_{2}|`{3})(.*?)\1|^\*\s*(.*?)$'
    passages = re.find_all(pattern, markdown_text)

    # Remove leading and trailing whitespace from each passage
    passages = [passage.strip() for passage in passages]
    
    # Remove empty passages
    passages = [passage for passage in passages if passage]
    
    return passages

markdown_text = """
## Introduction
This is the introduction paragraph.
### Subheading 1
This is the first subheading paragraph.
This is another paragraph under subheading 1.
**Subheading 2**
This is the second subheading paragraph.
_Subheading 3_
This is the **third subheading** paragraph.
Another paragraph without subheading.
"""

passages = markdown_to_passages(markdown_text)

# Print the resulting passages
for passage in passages:
    print(passage)
    print("*******************")
```